# How do I take off my pants?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

So I was in my *New Leaf* house and I accidentally put on a pair of pants instead of displaying them. Then I went and clicked on myself and I have no option to take off my pants. Ever. I swapped them with another pair for the display, but I can't get those off either. And the weird bit is when I put on the pants nothing was swapped back to my inventory.

How do I take off my pants?

Comment: I also considered: "Pants: Removing them from myself. How?"

Comment: I've said it before and I'll say it again, but this SE has the *best* question titles.

Comment: @Shadur Agreed. I love those kind of titles; they're always good for a laugh!

Comment: One of my life goals is to get stuck in a game and legitimately ask "How do I put on my wizard robe and hat?".

Comment: In Guild Wars 2, if you play as a sylvari (plant person) you start out naked because you were just born. You're supposed to talk to the first NPC that you see to get clothes, but one of my friends didn't realize this and spent her first 10 minutes running around asking people why she was naked.

Comment: You have to be wearing some kind of pants or shirt. It will just give you an under shirt or a grey skirt.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I have mastered taking off my pants!

To remove your pants, simply put on a full-length dress. This places your shirt and pants into your inventory. Then just put on a different shirt and boom, you got your dress off and your pants off!

I have also just discovered the same method can be used to remove your shirt as well! Instead of re-equiping a shirt after putting on a dress, instead put on pants or a skirt and you will have no shirt!

Comment: Pix or it didn't happen. ;)

Comment: It fills my heart with joy that the answer boils down to 'cross-dressing'.

Answer (score 7):

You always have to be wearing pants of some kind (or a skirt or a dress) in the game, you can not just remove what you have one. You will always have to swap them out for something else.

As mentioned by FAE: The default pants are not put into your inventory, also patterned clothing in general will just go back to being a pattern and will not give you a clothing item.

Comment: Right, I forgot to include that whatever I was wearing wasn't put into my inventory.

Comment: @Cyberskull If you were only wearing the default pants, then you don't get them to keep in your inventory, they just disappear.

Comment: @FAE but you can get the default pants back! See my [answer above](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/120740/9300)!

Answer (score 2):

I just make a new dress design out of one I wore, lost both the shirt and the pants. It's basically the undershirt and underwear you're left with.